# Azure Functions (Node.js) showing wrong Invocation Log in Kudu

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Summary: I have 2 different Azure Function Apps (Node.js), sharing a single file storage account, however if I go into the Kudu Invocation Logs for either of them I see the entries from both Apps.

Here is my setup:

- 1 File Storage (shared by both Function Apps)
- Service Bus 1 (`sb-prod`), with a single queue (`somequeue`)
- Service Bus 2 (`sb-staging`), with a single queue (`somequeue`)
- Function App 1 (`func-prod`), with a single function (`somefunc`)
- Function App 2 (`func-staging`), with a single function (`somefunc`)
- Both `func-prod` and `func-staging` are setup for continuous deployment from the same Bitbucket repo, but different branches
- When a message is received in `sb-prod` it triggers `somefunc` in `func-prod`
- When a message is received in `sb-staging` it triggers `somefunc` in `func-staging`

Note that the queue name and function name are the same in both prod and staging. That all seems to work fine. However if I go into Kudu and look at the Invocation Logs for debugging, it shows the execution of functions across both Function Apps (prod and staging shown in the logs for both). It is not respecting the folder structure on the file storage to only show the logs from the appropriate App. As far as I can tell, this is only a log viewing issue, and the functions aren't being run twice or messages being sent to the wrong function app. Any ideas on how to fix this? Or is this a bug and I would need to add a second storage account to fix it so that Kudu doesn't get confused? Is there any risk with this setup that messages from staging service bus end up in the prod app or vice versa?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by invocation log in Kudu? Do you mean you are manually looking at the *.log files under Debug Console? If so, are you looking at the Host level logs, or the function level logs?

Comment: I'm guessing he means the WebJobs dashboard (which is not related to Kudu). @Joel: are you by a chance hard coding a host id in your host.json? If you have the same in both apps, that could cause that.

Comment: Actually, that's not the problem. I added an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'Kudu', I assume you mean the WebJobs Dashboard (not related to Kudu). The behavior you are seeing is quirky, but is in fact by design. See https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1541 for more info.

Workarounds:

- The best is to use App Insights instead of the WebJobs Dashboard
- If you must use the WebJobs Dashboard, use distinct storage accounts

Comment: Yes, I meant the WebJobs Dashboard. The link is right on point. I did not enable Application Insights as I thought that would increase cost for a pretty trivial function, but on closer investigation it looks like it would be free if the log size stays under 5gb/month so that sounds like the way to go.